# evento scroll en javascript

Tags: javascript, menú, scroll

estoy haciendo un menú que tiene un margin-top para que no quede arriba, la cosa es que quiero que al hacer scroll quiero que este menú  tenga un margin top 0 pero no he podido lograrlo ya que no se como hacerlo con javascript. aquí el código que estaba haciendo.

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.margin ="100px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con la propiedad CSS `position: sticky;` sin necesitar el uso de javascript, espero que sea lo que necesites,.

Explicación:
El div con el id **myDIV** con la regla CSS `position: sticky;` es tratado como un elemento posicionado relativamente hasta que su bloque contenedor cruza un límite establecido (como por ejemplo dando a top cualquier valor distinto de auto), en este caso es `top:0;`

Fuente de explicación: [position- CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Ejemplo</title>
 <style>
  #myDIV {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
  }

  .box {
   padding: 2rem;
   margin: 2rem;
   color: #fff;
  }

  .box-lg {
   padding: 7rem 2rem;
  }

  .bg-red {
   background-color: red;
  }

  .bg-blue {
   background-color: blue;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="myDIV" class="box bg-red">Menu</div>
 <div class="box box-lg bg-blue">Caja 1</div>
 <div class="box box-lg bg-blue">Caja 2</div>
 <div class="box box-lg bg-blue">Caja 3</div>
 <div class="box box-lg bg-blue">Caja 4</div>
 <div class="box box-lg bg-blue">Caja 5</div>
</body>
</html>
```